# Regarding Keras mean_squared_error losses

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, regression

I am trying to do a `RandomizedSearchCV` for a simple regression task. Essentially two inputs to one output.

Upon inspecting the resulting models, it appears that the 'best' model has a mean_squared_error of around -8.3, while there were other 'non-best' models which had mean_squared_error close to 0 (i.e. around 0.004).

In this case, may I know if the Keras optimized model selection is correct? Why does it select one with `mean_squared_error` not close to zero?

Shouldn't the best model give MSE close to zero? I understand that the optimization seeks to minimize loss, but how can I interpret this?

Comment: You can't have an MSE of -8.3, because it's a **squared** error, meaning its always positive. This is probably a bug of the code or a wrong implementation from your part. In any case the optimizer is doing its job, the loss function is wrong! If you post more information (and the code) maybe we can help.

Comment: based on some earlier topics, it seems MSE can be negative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443865/scikit-learn-cross-validation-negative-values-with-mean-squared-error due to minimizing scheme. The thing im not sure is, why doesn't the randomsearch pick the model with MSE close to zero?

Comment: Hmm it says that it return by default negative MSE instead of positive MSE for some reason. In this case you want to maximize it instead of minimizing it...

Comment: that will be rather strange...

Comment: From what Fred Foo says in the post you mentioned: *when the unified scoring API was introduced, we decided to always maximize the score, which means scores that are actually losses need to be negated.*

Comment: i understand that, what about choosing the best model with MSE close to zero, instead of MSE being the 'most' negative?

Comment: Maximizing a negative quantity means moving it closer to zero, so we're saying the same thing essentially